# Spring boot integration test injecting mock object via autowire

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, integration-testing

I  am using spring boot with java based configurations. I have following classes structure

```
@Service
public class Service implements IService{
    @autowire
    private IProcessor processor;

    public void perform(Parameter param){
        processor.process(param);
    }
}

@Service
public class Processor implements IProcessor {
    @autowire
    private ProxyFactory factory;

    public void process(Parameter param){
        final ExternalSysProxy proxy = factory.get(param.getValue(), param.getId());
        proxy.call();
    }
}

@Repository
public class ProxyFactory {
    public Proxy get(String value, String id){
        final ExternalSysProxy proxy = new proxy(value, id);
        return proxy;
    }
}
```

The proxy object here makes call to external system. I want to write integration test by mocking proxy object. Can you please give me some guidance how I can inject mock proxy object in this structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the ProxyFactory and return the mock of the Proxy when call ProxyFactory.get(String value, String id)

I like to use Mockito in my unit tests:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ProcessorTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Processor processor;

    @Mock
    private ProxyFactory proxyFactoryMock;

    @Mock
    private Proxy proxyMock;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        Mockito.when(proxyFactoryMock.get("value", "id")).thenReturn(proxyMock);

        processor.process(new Parameter("value", "id"));

        Mockito.verify(proxyMock, Mockito.times(1)).call();
    }

}
```

Comment: how can I inject mock of ProxyFactory in my Processor class as ProxyFactory is auto discovered by spring and injected